# Why can I not call my PHP script from HTML button?

Tags: php, html, cookies

I am using a button from my HTML script to unset cookies, but currently I cannot make that call to the PHP script through that button click.

**HTML script**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>WCSST 2</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type='text/css'>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button style="color: black" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["name"])) { ?> Disabled <?php } ?> value='Set Cookie'><b>Unset cookie</b></button>

<!-- END PAGE SOURCE -->
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php

unset($_COOKIE['name']);
unset($_COOKIE['age']);

header("Location: CM.php");
exit(0);
}
?>
```

How can I make that call to the PHP script through that button click?

Comment: PHP will not execute in html file.

Comment: save your html script as **filename.php** rather than **filename.html**

Comment: is there any way to do this then? :)

Comment: @codehx yes it is already saved like that

Comment: @user3584871 if so you can use call your php script from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>WCSST 2</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type='text/css'>
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["name"])) { ?>
        <button style="color: black" onclick="window.location.href='unset.php'"><b>Unset cookie</b></button>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <button style="color: black" onclick="window.location.href='set.php'"><b>Set cookie</b></button>
        <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

unset.php script

```
<?php

unset($_COOKIE['name']);
unset($_COOKIE['age']);

header("Location: CM.php");
exit(0);
}
?>
```

set.php script

```
<?php
// set your cookie
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

your html script must have `.php` extension becuase it have php script.

for example `example.php` -- > contain your html script.

you called to unset file using **include** statement

```
<body>

    <button style="color: black" <?php 
       if(isset($_COOKIE["name"])) 
        { 
          include 'unset.php'; 
        } 
        ?> value='Set Cookie'>
   <b>Unset cookie</b></button>

<!-- END PAGE SOURCE -->
</body>
```

Or you can use `JAVASCRIPT` **onclick function**

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is make the button call a javascript function, the function will call an Ajax which will execute your PHP code.

your HTML file:

```
<button onclick='my_func();'>Click me</button>
```

Your javascript (include jQuery to make life easier)

```
function my_func()
{
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'unset.php',
      data: {},
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function (data) {},
      error: function() {}
    });
}
```

Comment: why datatype is json?

Comment: it does not matter. No data is being transmitted. Only a call to the PHP file will suffice. @Prashant

Answer (score 1):

You should use a form to call a `PHP` script. You can do that like this:

```
<form action="unset.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Unset cookie">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first of all you cant write php script code into .html file, so for that create .php file and in that write above your whole code. and one more thing is for unset cookies in you have to send post request using normally form method or you can also use ajax call
for e.g

```html
<form name="abc" id="abc" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="unset" value="Unset Cookies">
</form>


<?php
if($_POST)
{
unset($_COOKIE['name']);
unset($_COOKIE['age']);

header("Location: CM.php");
exit(0);
}
?>
```